# Is there any way to get the correct time format as expected in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using the below condition to convert datetime to hh:mm am or pm, but am getting 'dec 11 2015 11:01AM'. i need only '11:01am' as output. can anyone please help me ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `cast` the date to `time` before applying the `style`

Try this

```
SELECT convert(varchar(30), cast(getdate() as time), 0)
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6269)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 100), 7))
```